# Using PHP namespaces in a Zend Framework (v1) application

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, autoload, zend-autoloader

Is it possible in the current stable version of the Zend Framework (1.11), to work with application classes using PHP namespaces?

```
Application\Form\Abc instead of Application_Form_Abc
Application\Model\Xyz instead of Application_Model_Xyz
etc.
```

Starting from v1.10, ZF supports [autoloading namespaces](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html), and it's working fine when including namespaced libraries, but I was unsuccessful when trying to do the same job with application classes.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691793/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-zend-framework

Comment: @Rufinus: nope, I did have a look at this question, which is 2 years old. The namespace autoloading support was not out at this time, and the author was asking if it was possible to *modify* ZF to support this feature. I'm asking if *a subset* of this feature is *built-in* now; they're talking about the internal ZF classes, while I just want my **application classes** to use namespaces, I don't care extending ZF's non-namespaced classes.

Comment: you just have to take care of the autoloader, look for doctrine 2.0 integration tutorials, they have use namespaces and have an own autoloader which is used by zend_loader.

Comment: @Rufinus: as I mentioned, the autoloader currently shipped with ZF already handles namespaces. But I'm talking about the ZF-specific mapping from e.g. `Application_Form_Abc` to `/application/forms/Abc.php`, which is different from the standard mapping.

Comment: This more recent SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409424/zend-resource-autoloaders-not-working-for-namespaces) discusses it, but (so far) comes to the conclusion that @Benjamin notes: the ZF1 autoloader *does* handle namespaces, but `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` *does not*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually there is a simple workaround [suggested by Dmitry on the ZF issue tracker](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8205#comment-43972):

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoloader()
    {
        $loader = function($className) {
            $className = str_replace('\\', '_', $className);
            Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload($className);
        };

        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->pushAutoloader($loader, 'Application\\');
    }
}
```

Works like a charm for me!

Answer (score 6):

The standard autloader introduced in 1.12 allows you to use namespaces with minimal effort:

```
require 'Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
Zend_Loader_AutoloaderFactory::factory([
    'Zend_Loader_StandardAutoloader' => [
        'autoregister_zf' => true,
        'namespaces' => [
            'Application' => '/path/to/Application/src',
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Now you can use `Application\Form\Abc` instead of `Application_Form_Abc` & `Application\Model\Xyz` instead of `Application_Model_Xyz` etc.

Directory/File structure examples:

path/to/Application/src/Form/Abc.php

```
<?php
namespace Application/Form;
class Abc {}
```

path/to/Application/src/Model/Xyz.php

```
<?php
namespace Application/Model;
class Xyz {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting your controllers to work and not just the forms and models :) Take a look at the Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:174

```
public function formatClassName($moduleName, $className)
```

You would need to swap the _ with "\" as well in order to get the correct class name.

Comment: I would advise to move away from ZF1 in 2022, if you can ;-)

Comment: Some projects you cannot move they've been working forever so to maintain the old code and implement something new is nice.