# Doctrine 2 + Zend Framework Proxy generation

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am trying to mix doctrine 2 along with Zend framework, and I am using Zend auto loader. so All my Entities is looked like

`TEST_ORM_Entities_User` under `TEST/ORM/Entites/User.php`

but there is a problem with serialization since all proxies will look like

`Pocks\ORM\Proxies\TEST_ORM_Entities_UserProxy` under `TEST/ORM/Proxies/TEST_ORM_Entities_UserProxy.php`

So doctine can't find my proxy classes, and when I check my cache I found it corrupted

```
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#175 (19) {
  ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
  string(46) "TEST\ORM\Proxies\TEST_ORM_Entities_UserProxy"
```

Any Idea how we can explicitly put the Proxy File Name, or solving this issue?

Comment: Use proper namespacing for your entities. I'm pretty sure this is mandatory in Doctrine 2

Comment: That is exactly my question, naming between Zend and Doctrine, Entities are valid according to ZEND :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into the same problem in the past, and ended up converting our application to use namespaces as well.

We still use Zend Framework 1.x and its pseudo-namespace convention, but all of our application classes are namespaced thanks to [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513529/using-php-namespaces-in-a-zend-framework-v1-application).

Now our code looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Form;
use Zend_Form as Form;

class UserForm extends Form
{
    // ...
}
```

And we can refer to this class by `Application\Form\UserForm` anywhere in the code, thanks to the autoloader fix!

Comment: Yeh, look like a good answer, but I create a different solution, I changed the proxies location (namespace) out of the Zend autoloader, so zend can't see my proxies anymore :)