# Cant understand what's happening

Tags: php, zend-framework, crypt

i'm trying Zend framework, i've got two folders in *E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\ZendServer\share*, une is ZendServer and the other one is ZendServer2
I can't recall if i ever install this two version but i dont think this is the problem
I'm using netbeans as ide ando i'm trying to make an ABM of users using BlockCipher
Here is my code

```
<?php
use Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher;
class Application_Model_DbTable_Usuarios extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'usuario';

    public function getUsuario($usuario)
    {
        $usuario = (string)$usuario;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('Usuario = ' . $usuario);
        if (!$row) {
            throw new Exception("Could not find row $usuario");
        }
        return $row->toArray();
    }

    public function addUsuario($usuario, $clave)
    {

       $blockCipher = Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher::factory('mcrypt',array('algo'=>'aes'));
       $blockCipher->setKey('encryption key');
       $result = $blockCipher->encrypt($clave);
       echo "Encrypted text: $result \n";
       exit;
       $data = array(
            'Usuario' => $usuario,
            'Clave' => $blockCipher,
        );
        $this->insert($data);

    }

    public function updateUsuario($usuario, $clave)
    {
        $blockCipher =  BlockCipher::factory($clave, array(
                                'algo' => 'blowfish',
                                'mode' => 'cfb',
                                'hash' => 'sha512'
                        ));
        $data = array(
            'Clave' => $blockCipher,
        );
        $this->update($data, 'Usuario = ' . (string)$usuario);

    }

    public function deleteUsuario($usuario)
    {
        $this->delete('Usuario = ' . (string)$usuario);
    }

}
```

and in my php.ini i've got 
`include_path=".;E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework2\library"`

And i get this error

`Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher' not found in E:\Documents and Settings\dvieira\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\justforgeeks\application\models\DbTable\Usuarios.php on line 21`

I dont understand why.
Can you help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use ZF2 classes in a ZF1 app. Can you confirm which version of ZF you're using?

Comment: could be, but i dot think so, when i try phpinfo it shows
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Extension Manager v5.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2010, by Zend Technologies

Comment: None of those relate to Zend Framework. Can you provide more info about the file structure of your application?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, searching how to realize whats my zend version i've found:
http://localhost:10081/ZendServer/Index/Index#1377541716060
There it says:
Zend Framework Version  1.12.0 
I think this could be the problem.
Y will try to update to zend 2.0.
Thankyou again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using namespaces in your application, therefore you need to make sure that your autoloader can handle this. If it's a ZF1 app then not. Can you try using require to include the class file instead? You can ass well amend the autoloader to [work with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513529/using-php-namespaces-in-a-zend-framework-v1-application)

Secondly when using namespaces, if you create an alias for a class

```
use Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher;
```

you then instantiate it

```
$blockCipher = BlockCipher::factory('mcrypt',array('algo'=>'aes'));
```

Comment: Thank you, it result i have zend1.12, i will update and try again.